How is gravitational lensing related to Fermat's principle of least time?
I'm learning about the Fermat's principle of least time (FPLT) for how light refracts on entering water. Is gravitational lensing (around a star or galaxy) related to FPLT?  From what I understand gravitational lensing is not refraction, because then we would see a rainbow in the bent light, but we don't. What is the relation between them?

There is no connection between these two laws. lensing has nothing to do with refraction.

Related: Does gravitational lensing violate Fermat's Principle that light must travel in straight lines?, Fermat's principle in classical mechanics?

Gravitational attraction is towards the region of greatest time, no?

Yes, there is a version of Fermat's principle adapted for general relativity! Like many situations in physics, it's an example of a principle of stationary action: Fermat is the name for the special case for light. You can derive the equations for the deflection of light around a mass, like a galaxy or star, using it.
This paper and this paper from the 90s were the ones which gave a derivation for an arbitrary spacetime. The tricky part to the idea of a Fermat principle for gravitational lensing is that the idea of "time" in general relativity is a bit more slippery than in Newtonian physics. In general we don't have a global concept of time; and light doesn't have a proper time. The remarkable thing that Kovner and Perlick showed was that we can still apply a version of Fermat, if we consider the idea of an "arrival time functional".
The general relativistic version of the Fermat principle states that

Let there be a null curve P from a fixed photon emission event to a possible observation event at its intersection with a timelike observer worldline. Then this P is a null geodesic (i.e. a light ray) if and only if the functional of its arrival time, measured along the observer worldline, is stationary with respect to variations of P restricted to null curves.

Basically, we are are considering possible arrival times measured by the observer, instead of a Newtonian time.
